# htaccess remove get parameter keys not value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove the get keys from my url,

So `test?category=innate&index=0` would become `test/innate/0`.

I have been trying all day to no avail. I find resources very hard to learn apache. Any **point** in the right direction would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root

```
RewriteEngine On

# to externally redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /test\?category=([^&]+)&index=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^test$ /test/%1/%2 [L,R=301]

# to internally rewrite back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /test?category=$1&index=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the external as well :)

Answer (score 1):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ test?category=$1&index=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)